# Are questions about ways to promote your game on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic

Is a question about ways to promote your game, pricing, distribution way, etc.. appropriate question for the game dev community? If not which one would be most suitable if any?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Generally questions asking for *lists of things*, regardless of the topic, aren't on-topic. If you have a specific question about a *specific* method of promotion or distribution, or a problem you're having with it, that would probably be on-topic.

But if you're just looking for *ideas* on how to promote or market things, you may want to try asking somewhere like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: @vadim And remember, it's not about how to promote *your* game specifically. It's about the specific method of promotion or distribution. We don't want to see a link to your game in the question.